# Storing Prices with Cents in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, currency, stripe-payments

Ok I have a Stripe charge to which I am applying taxes. Stripe takes in a number as cents, so it leaves you with a number like 10015 instead of 100.15.

In my controller, I am sending the number to ActiveRecord as 10015/100.0

When I retrieve it, it gives me `#<BigDecimal:7fca81f71130,'0.1243E3',18(27)>>`

Whats going on ?

I tried

`rails g migration add_expense_to_user expense:integer`

and

`rails g migration add_expense_to_user expense:decimal`

to whose migration I added

`add_column :user, :expense, :decimal, precision: 6, scale: 2`

which is the current setup.

How do I store / retrieve the value if it is stored as 10015/100

Comment: What is the "chipmunk gibberish" you speak of? It would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: @alephtwo edited, and boo for the downvote.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @holgerjust edited once again

Comment: You're being spat back a BigDecimal object, which makes me suspect it's a bad migration. Your last code snippet looks fine, but double check that. It might also have something to do with ActiveRecord's interface to your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` is just the type that Rails uses for `decimal` types in DBs.  `0.1243E3` is scientific notation, short for `0.1243 x 10³` - ie. `124.3`

You can get a regular float from it by just using the `.to_f` method in Ruby, or you can pass a `BigDecimal` into other Rails helpers, like `number_to_currency(the_big_decimal)` will produce `"$124.30"`

So, in other words, with the BigDecimal you probably already have what you're asking for in this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you access the data, you need to call `.to_f`.

In irb:

```
a = BigDecimal.new(5, 2)
a
=> #<BigDecimal:1ad7c98,'0.5E1',9(27)> 
a.to_f
=> 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is stored inside the BigDecimal object with arbitrary precision. The "common" representation of non-integer values (i.e. floats) however doesn't provide this precision. Thus, BigDecimal provides various options to convert its value to other types.

You can e.g use `expense.to_f` to get a floating point representation of the BigDecimal value (and thus loosing the precision along the way). Alternatively, if you just want to print the value, you could use one of the `to_s` method to format the value as a string:

```
expense.to_s
# => "124.3"
```

See the [BigDecimal documentation](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) for details.

Comment: Is it not inevitable that a system would lose such precision? Unless the charges are all being made to the same customer, in which case you can tally, you are bound to either lose or steal money when rounding from the 3rd decimal no ? @holgerjust